# Abstract class with minor differences in implementers

Tags: c++, oop, abstract-class

In a current project, I have classes named `BlahManager` and class named `BlahController`, defined like this:

```
class BlahController
{
public:

   void doSomething(int x, float y){
        // do the work
   }
   void doOtherThing(char a, char* b, int c){
        // do the work
    }
}

class BlahManager
{
public:
   BlahController m_controllers[5];

   void doSomething(int blahIndex, int x, float y){
       m_controllers[blahIndex].doSomething(x,y);
   }
   void doOtherThing(int blahIndex, char a, char* b, int c){
       m_controllers[blahIndex].doOtherThing(a,b,c);
    }
}
```

Is their anyway to make abstract class which defines functions `doSomething` and `doOtherthing` only once, and make both class Manager and Controller implement it?

I want to do this to force the similarity of function names/parameters between the Manager and the Controller.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to wrap the `BlahController` methods and not just expose the controllers via something like `BlahController & GetController(size_t blahIndex)` (or even an `operator[]` if appropriate)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and you shouldn't.

`BlahController::doSomething` takes 2 parameters, while `BlahManager::doSomething` takes 3. So you cannot have an abstract parent class forcing the two classes to implement the same function, because they are **not** the same function.

Also, you shouldn't even want to do this. These functions don't do similar jobs. For example if you have `draw` for `class Circle` and `class Triangle`, they are doing similar jobs. But here, one is performing a job, while the other is managing it. So, even if the function signatures were similar, I would never make them inherit it from a common parent!

Comment: If somebody else is going to write these functions and you want to force them to write compatible signatures, just a put a note, either in the code or separate file and tell them to do it. You shouldn't take the programmer as an idiot. (That is, if he is an idiot, fire him)

Comment: I loved the firing idea, the bad part is that you can't fire customers :D

Comment: Ah the lovely customer. I always say: "When you buy a car, you don't tell the company how to make every little detail of it. You just go and choose what you like. If you're buying software, you can't tell me how to write it. You either like it and buy it, or go away" (Well, I work in the university, so I don't have a direct customer. I'm pretty sure in business though this sentence can get you bankrupt in no time! :D We have been treating the customers too well, they think they can say anything)

Comment: But seriously, WHY is your customer concerned about the signature of your functions?!

Comment: @Shahbaz: Maybe that customer is a programmer and will use your library in their code?

Comment: the customer will implement these classes, so I was thinking about giving one abstract class for both Manager and Controller, instead of one abstract class for Manager and another one for Controller.